# How does this keyword work on a function call chain?

Tags: javascript, this

I was reading about *this* keyword in Kyle Simpson's 'You Don't know JS Series'. In the book,  one of the concepts he explains on the *this* keyword is *Default Binding.* The this keyword used in a function object is based on the call site of the function. If the function call occurs on a global scope, then the *this* keyword used in the called function represents the global scope.
Consider the example,

```
var a=100;

function fun(){
    var a=10;
    console.log(this.a);
}

fun();   // outputs 100
```

Now I was trying to understand better and tried out this example,

```
var a=100;

function f1(){
   console.log(this.a);
}

function f2(){
   var a=10;
    f1();
}

f2();         // outputs 100 and not 10. Why?
```

Since the call to function f1 happened in the context of function f2, I thought *this.a* in function f1 might output to 10. But instead it outputs to 100. How does this happen?

Comment: Scope of topmost i.e. this.a is global for every function as everyone's this will be same. Now your next "a=10" is local for f1 also. So same value is printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you can bind the `var a` of `f2` to `this` of f1,  `var a` of `f2` is just a local variable in scope of `f2`, it has nothing to do with `this` keyword since it is just a normal local variable.

The implicit binding mentioned in You don't know JS, which is the most common way to use `this` keyword. What the book means is that `this` keyword only depends on the object which uses dot notation to reference, in your example, since `f1` is called without any object attached to it, the only rule which can be applied to it is default binding.

Answer (score 0):

f1 will log the global this.a which = 100 since no other assignment of a was in f1. Since you are still calling f1() inside of your f2() function, f1 still reads the global a which is 100. Had you had f2() {a=10};
And called f2(); you would return 10. Don’t call f1() inside of your f2 function, but still remember to include console.log( this.a ); in both functions.

Answer (score 0):

`var a=100;` is a variable defined in a global scope and accessible to any function.
`var a=10;` is a local variable defined in the scope of `f2` function available only inside of this function.

`this.a` references the global variable as local variable `a` defined in the scope of `f2` function is not available in `f1`

Comment: Then how come Implicit Binding works? consider,                                                    
 var a=100;                             
function foo() {
console.log( this.a );
}
var obj = {
a: 42,
foo: foo
};

obj.foo(); // 42  .   Foo is called in the context of Object obj Similar to f1 being called in the context of f2 function?

Comment: obj a is reassigned to 42 and you’re calling obj.foo which is calling the variable inside the object.